# Empty ghost Popup when dynamically rendering popup in react-leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm dynamically rendering a marker popup in `react-leaflet` via a series of nested marker elements: `DonutMarker`, `BoundsDriftMarker`, and `DriftMarker`. The `Popup` is created in `DonutMarker` [(GitHub)](https://github.com/VEuPathDB/mapveu/blob/ad0134a19642565c183f2c35a17e76a526cedf07/src/map/DonutMarker.tsx#L151-L164) and passed to `BoundsDriftMarker` as a prop:

```
export default function DonutMarker(props: DonutMarkerProps) {
  ...
  return (
    <BoundsDriftMarker
      ...
      popup={
        <Popup>
          ...
          test
        </Popup>
      }
      showPopup={props.showPopup}
    />
  );
}
```

then from `BoundsDriftMarker` [(GitHub)](https://github.com/VEuPathDB/mapveu/blob/ad0134a19642565c183f2c35a17e76a526cedf07/src/map/BoundsDriftMarker.tsx#L63) it's dynamically rendered as a child to `DriftMarker`:

```
export default function BoundsDriftMarker({position, bounds, icon, duration, popup, showPopup}: BoundsDriftMarkerProps) {
  ...
  return (<DriftMarker
    ...
  >
    ...
    {showPopup && popup}
  </DriftMarker>)
}
```

This is what it looks like currently when `showPopup == true`, along with the React browser plugin correctly showing the Popup element under the marker:

[image] [image]

However, when I switch `showPopup == false` after this, I get an empty popup even though the browser plugin shows no popup:

[image] [image]

Are the nested marker components causing this issue, or is there some other problem?

Answer (score 1):

try [Seth Lutske](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12010984/seth-lutske) answer in

[react-leaflet: Clear marker cluster before rendering new markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67712024/react-leaflet-clear-marker-cluster-before-rendering-new-markers)

He wraps markers in MarkerClusterGroup, and change the key every time he need to refresh markers in map. Works for me too

```
  <MarkerClusterGroup
    key={uuidv4()}  
    spiderfyDistanceMultiplier={1}
    showCoverageOnHover={true}
>
```