# How to change the options of React MarkerClusterGroup when MarkerClusterGroup is a parent element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

Im am using leaflet cluster library (v1.1.8) and i am trying to pass options.

I want the app to stop showing coverage on hover (see picture below).
[image]

But whenever i add the options `showCoverageOnHover={false}` it does not work.

```
<MarkerClusterGroup  showCoverageOnHover={false}>

  <MarkersLayer
    stationsToDisplay={stationsToDisplay}
    stationsList={stationsList}
    refreshStationsList={this.refreshStationsList}
    StandsToDisplay={StandsToDisplay}
    CARToDisplay={CARToDisplay}
    selectedOption={selectedOption}
  />

  </MarkerClusterGroup >
```

The [documentation](https://github.com/YUzhva/react-leaflet-markercluster/blob/HEAD/CHANGELOG.md#v118) shows that the correct code to pass options would be :

```
<MarkerClusterGroup showCoverageOnHover={false} />
```

However, i am passing already  as a prop :

```
     <MarkerClusterGroup  >

      <MarkersLayer
        stationsToDisplay={stationsToDisplay}
        stationsList={stationsList}
        refreshStationsList={this.refreshStationsList}
        StandsToDisplay={StandsToDisplay}
        CARToDisplay={CARToDisplay}
        selectedOption={selectedOption}
      />

      </MarkerClusterGroup >
```

Then how do i pass the option ? I have tried inside the  , as below but this does not work

```
<MarkersLayer
            stationsToDisplay={stationsToDisplay}
            stationsList={stationsList}
            refreshStationsList={this.refreshStationsList}
            StandsToDisplay={StandsToDisplay}
            CARToDisplay={CARToDisplay}
            selectedOption={selectedOption}
            showCoverageOnHover={false}
          />
```

I am quite a noob in react, so any observation and suggestion would be much appreciated ! thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

According to the new API version on 1.1.8, something like this will work:

```
<MarkerClusterGroup showCoverageOnHover={false} >
  <MarkersLayer
    stationsToDisplay={stationsToDisplay}
    stationsList={stationsList}
    refreshStationsList={this.refreshStationsList}
    StandsToDisplay={StandsToDisplay}
    CARToDisplay={CARToDisplay}
    selectedOption={selectedOption}
  />
</MarkerClusterGroup >
```

Another example of using `markerClusterGroup` might be useful:

```
import MarkerClusterGroup from 'react-leaflet-markercluster';

<MarkerClusterGroup>
  <Marker position={[49.8397, 24.0297]} />
  <Marker position={[52.2297, 21.0122]} />
  <Marker position={[51.5074, -0.0901]} />
</MarkerClusterGroup>;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried that that but it does not work . This link shows the same so I think you are right. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67712024/react-leaflet-clear-marker-cluster-before-rendering-new-markers. But my problem is probably somewhere else

Comment: I'm agreeing with you. You may need to ask another question with details of the error or your expectation and the behavior of the current implementation. @GuillaumeLabs

Answer (score 0):

By adding the parameters that way in the class itself, fixes the issue :

```
class MarkerClusterGroup extends MapLayer {
  createLeafletElement(props) {
    const el = new L.markerClusterGroup(
      {
        props,

        showCoverageOnHover:false,
        disableClusteringAtZoom: 13,
    }
      );
    this.contextValue = {
      ...props.leaflet,

      layerContainer: el
    };
    return el;
  }
  
}
export default withLeaflet(MarkerClusterGroup);
```